Select parent and only some fields from child in @OneToMany relationships using JPA and Criteria Builder
Implemented one to many relationship and select parent and child I have a onetomany relationship.
Using criteria builder, i need to get parent and all related childs but  selecting only some fields from each child.
@Entity
@Table(name="transaction_status")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TransactionStatus implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@JsonProperty("id")
public String id;

@SerializedName("status")
public String status;

@Column(name="lastUpdatedDate")
@JsonProperty("lastUpdatedDate")
@SerializedName("lastUpdatedDate")
private Date lastUpdatedDate;

@JsonProperty("generatedAt")
@SerializedName("generatedAt")
@JsonIgnore
private Date generatedAt;

@JsonProperty("invoices")
@SerializedName("invoices")
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="transactionstatusId",referencedColumnName = "xmlFilename")
private List<InvoiceTransaction> invoiceTransactions = new ArrayList<>();

}
@Entity
@Table(name="invoice_transaction")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class InvoiceTransaction implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("status")
    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
    @Column(name = "originalStatus", nullable = false)
    @JsonProperty("originalStatus")
    @SerializedName("originalStatus")
    private String originalStatus;
    
    @Column(name = "errorMessage")
    @JsonProperty("errorMessage")
    @SerializedName("errorMessage")
    private String errorMessage;

    @Column(name = "generatedAt" )
    @JsonProperty("generatedAt")
    @SerializedName("generatedAt")
    private Date generatedAt;
}

CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TransactionStatus> cq = builder.createQuery(TransactionStatus.class);
Root<TransactionStatus> rootTrnStatus = cq.from(TransactionStatus.class);
List<TransactionStatus> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

this implementation, gives me list of Transactionstatus objetc with list of its childs. what im seraching to get is:
list of Transactionstatus object with list of its childs with olny status and errorMessage fileds. How can i get this result using Crtiteria builder?
thank you

To achieve your desired result of selecting only specific fields from the child entity (InvoiceTransaction), you can use the Criteria API to create a query that retrieves the parent entity (TransactionStatus) along with a projection for the child entity's fields. Here's how you can modify your Criteria query to achieve this:
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<TransactionStatus> rootTrnStatus = cq.from(TransactionStatus.class);
Join<TransactionStatus, InvoiceTransaction> joinInvoice = rootTrnStatus.join("invoiceTransactions", JoinType.LEFT);

cq.select(builder.array(rootTrnStatus, joinInvoice.get("status"), joinInvoice.get("errorMessage")));

List<Object[]> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();

List<TransactionStatus> transactionStatusList = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object[] result : resultList) {
    TransactionStatus transactionStatus = (TransactionStatus) result[0];
    InvoiceTransaction invoiceTransaction = new InvoiceTransaction();
    invoiceTransaction.setStatus((String) result[1]);
    invoiceTransaction.setErrorMessage((String) result[2]);
    transactionStatus.getInvoiceTransactions().add(invoiceTransaction);
    transactionStatusList.add(transactionStatus);
}


Thank you for the reply. the only issue in this solution, that the List<Objetc[]> returns the entire child fields, then map them to the transactionStatusObject. some child fields are heavy and contains a large number of data that why i want to avoid selecting them.

filter them in code

could you please explain more? how can i filter them?

joinInvoice.get("status"), joinInvoice.get("errorMessage") here  has specified column, there is no sense get all column entired data , although i have not test it ;

Thank you @Peng, it gives ne a single class with the selected fields not parent, [child1,child2]

so is that worked? all thing is fine?

it is not what im searching to get. I need to get TransactionStatus[ id,status, invoiceTransactions[{status, errorMessage}, {status,errorMessage}]]
